# Can't access sass variables compile error with react app

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app

I am creating a react app with the `create-react-app` and I have tried to implement SASS pre-processor by following these steps over [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc). So everything went well and I have developed already some parts of my application. But for a really weird reason, I now got a error on compiling after already 2 days of development, without any reason I can imagine.

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "/Users/glenngijsberts/Documents/Development/toggle/src/components/sass/assets.scss",
  "line": 2,
  "column": 9,
  "message": "Undefined variable: \"$primary\".",
  "formatted": "Error: Undefined variable: \"$primary\".\n        on line 2 of src/components/sass/assets.scss\n>> \tcolor: $primary;\n   --------^\n"
}
```

So the main problem is that I get now a compile error because my `assets.scss` can't access the variables. Assets is imported in my App.scss which also imported variables.scss.

In my App.scss file

```
//Import SCSS
@import "./sass/vars.scss";

@import "./sass/popup.scss";
@import "./sass/assets.scss";
@import "./sass/utils.scss";
@import "./sass/modal.scss";
@import "./sass/dropdown.scss";
@import "./sass/visualLine.scss";
@import "./sass/dashboard.scss";
@import "./sass/tabs.scss";
@import "./sass/projects.scss";
@import  "./sass/colors.scss";
```

What is working is:

assets.scss

```
//Import SCSS
@import "vars.scss";

span.brand {
    color: $primary;
}
```

But ofcourse, I don't like to include that `vars` file on every scss file where I want to use a scss variable. I am not used to it either (when using just sass files with a regular webpack project).

Answer (score 0):

You have to put "_" to beginning name of every file you want to globally import. So your vars.scss would be _vars.scss. Sounds weird, but works.
If it won't help, rename your files to *.sass and use sass syntax. It is simplier and would work on 100%.